# Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed' in Python 3.9

Tags: python, json, csv, python-requests

This script is used to send data to a 3rd party. It seems to run fine when connected to any network other than my work network. When connected to my work network, it will run for a few minutes, PUT/POSTing as it should, and then suddenly the following error will appear:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\RPackages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 353, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000022FD9B44FA0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='vaccine-verify-v1.services.school.edu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/verify (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000022FD9B44FA0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\scripture\bali_vax.py", line 71, in <module>
    post_vax_record(row)
  File "C:\scripture\bali_vax.py", line 38, in post_vax_record
    response = requests.post(url,json=vaxrecord, headers=headers, timeout=5)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 117, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='vaccine-verify-v1.services.school.edu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/verify (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000022FD9B44FA0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Script

```py
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer() 

import requests

url = 'https://vaccine-verify-v1.services.school.edu/api/verify' 
client_id = "abc"
client_secret = "123"

def post_vax_record(record):
    manuallyVerified = record[7].lower() == "true"; 
    vaxrecord = { "firstName":record[0], "lastName": record[1], "dob": record[2], "phoneNumber": (record[3] or '4444444444'), "state": record[4], "zip": record[5][:5], "campusName": "Baltimore", "instituitionId": 0, "campusSuCd": 28, "sunyLanId": record[6], "sunyStudId": 0, "ssoId": "BEL-"+record[6], "manuallyVerified": manuallyVerified }
    headers = {'Client_Id':client_id, 'Client_Secret':client_secret,'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    response = requests.post(url,json=vaxrecord, headers=headers, timeout=5)
    if response:

        json_response = response.json()
        if ('message' in json_response and json_response['message'] ==  'The Student record already exists. Please use put operation to insert the record.'): #changed from update to insert
            print ('Post failed. Trying put instead')
            response = requests.put(url,json=vaxrecord, headers=headers)
            if response:
                print('Success on put for '+record[6])
            else:
                print('Put failed for '+record[6])
        else: 
            print('Success on post for '+record[6])
        print(response.json())  
    else:
        print('Post failed for '+record[6]+' with error code: ')
        print(response.status_code)
        
import csv
with open('data_file.csv') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        if row[6].upper().split('@')[1] in ("LIVE.LODI.EDU", "LODI.EDU"): 
          if row[0].upper() != "FIRSTNAME":
            row[6] = row[6].upper().split('@')[0]
            post_vax_record(row)
        else:
            print('NON-LODI EMAIL FOUND FOR '+row[1]+', '+row[0]+'. WILL NOT PROCESS RECORD!')
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Run Time: ', stop - start)
```

While testing this script, and using smaller CSVs (with less records to read in), I never had an issue. Just recently has this been occurring. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the hostname lookup (i.e. DNS) is failing sometimes. As the URL is always the same, you could try using a single requests session (i.e. with a persistent connection) for all PUT/POST

Comment: Thanks, it it possible to only lookup the DNS once at the beginning of my program, as opposed to doing it every time I read in a new record?

Comment: If you can make a persistent connection then maybe you’ll only do the DNS lookup once.

Comment: See https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects - you’ll also get faster performance because of SSL/TLS connection for https only being made once.

Answer (score 0):

Please wrap `response = requests.post(url,json=vaxrecord, headers=headers, timeout=5)` line with `try-catch` block

```
while retry_counter < 5:
  try:            
      response = requests.post(url,json=vaxrecord, headers=headers, timeout=5)
   except socket.error as error:
       print("Connection Failed due to socket - {}").format(error)
       print("Attempting {} of 5").format(retry_counter)
       time.sleep(3)
       retry_counter  += 1
```

NOTE: Generally retrying code after some time in socket error case will resolve the issue(happened in my case) hence the below solution

while doing `request.post`, if `socket.error` occurs then retry the code 3-5 time with a delay of your 1-3 seconds.